# Dictionary lookup with key as a matched group in python re.sub module

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Dictionary lookup with key as a matched group in python re.sub module

Solution1: ================Doesnt work================

```
dict1={}
dict1['indu']='sharma'
dict1['abhi']='dutta'
text='agan !abhi !indu Saikat'
text=re.sub('!(\w+)',dict1[r'\1'], text)
print text
```

Solution2:=========================Works!!!===========

```
dict1={}
dict1['indu']='sharma'
dict1['abhi']='dutta'
text='agan !abhi !indu Saikat'
text=re.sub('!(\w+)',lambda x: dict1[x.group(1)], text)
print text
```

How to make Solution1 working?

Comment: Why not lambda, problem?

Comment: you can't .. stick with 2.

Comment: `\1` works when it combined with strings. Incase of dict lookup, you must use anonymous function.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Note Python is not like Perl, the backreferences are not used as environment variables when you use regex with capturing groups.

Only the lambda code will work and there is no way to make a backreference work the same way.

The reason is evident: only `re.sub` knows what `\1` refers to, the `dict1` has no idea what `\1` points to. You pass the pattern with a capturing group to the `re.sub`, so, this method allows to use a *replacement pattern string* that can contain backreferences. You do not pass any pattern/regex to the dictionary (actually, you can't), so there is no way to use a regex backreference to get some dictionary value.