# Why does re.finditer seem to be ignoring the provided pattern?

Tags: python, regex

Maybe I'm misunderstanding how `re.finditer` works, but it seems to be ignoring the pattern I give it and matching on all instances of the character. For example, this code:

```
word = "aaaa"
for match in re.finditer(r"(?<=a)a(?=a)", word):
    word = re.sub(match.group(), "b", word)
```

is giving me `"bbbb"`, when I would expect it to give `"abba"`, like this code does:

```
word = "aaaa"
word = re.sub(r"(?<=a)a(?=a)", "b", word)
```

Any idea why matching through `re.finditer` seems to be working differently from doing it directly with `re.sub`?

EDIT: To clarify, what I'm actually trying to do is lookup what substitution to apply in a dictionary, but

```
word = re.sub(r"(?<=a)(a)(?=a)", d[r"\1"], word)
```

(where `d` is a dictionary) doesn't work because \1 is not a key, so I was hoping to iterate through and apply substitutions as I find them. I also can't just do a separate line for each substitution in the dictionary because I have a lot of changes that are circular, so a > b, b > c, and c > a, if that makes sense. In other words, if I try to apply the changes linearly, I'm going to end up back where I started. Maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, the value of `match.group()` is "a" at both iterations. `word = re.sub(match.group(), "b", word)` becomes `word = re.sub("a", "b", word)`, which naturally replaces each "a" with a "b".

In the second example, only the middle "a"'s are replaced.

Comment: Oh... that makes sense... For some reason I thought that it somehow kept track of the location of the match as well. Is there a way to manipulate it so it only subs the ones which actually match the pattern?

Comment: Sure there is: your second example is doing just that.

Comment: My issue is that in my actual code, I'm utilizing a dictionary to lookup what change to apply depending on the character, so I essentially need to find a match, look it up in the dictionary, apply the appropriate substitution AT THAT LOCATION ONLY, then continue with the search to find other matches.

Comment: I tried this: `word = re.sub(r"(?<=a)(a)(?=a)", d[r"\1"], word)`
where `d` is the dictionary, but that doesn't work.

Comment: This is a different question. Please update your original post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I was looking for here: [Dictionary lookup with key as a matched group in python re.sub module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564260/dictionary-lookup-with-key-as-a-matched-group-in-python-re-sub-module).

I didn't realize you can pass in a function as the second parameter to `sub`, so essentially, all you have to do is something like this to incorporate dictionary lookup into the substitution:

```
word = re.sub(r"(?<=a).(?=a)", lambda x: d[x.group()], word)
```